# Is it possible to implement (in Scala) a polymorphic wrapper class that automatically implements the methods of the wrapped class?

Tags: scala, reflection, polymorphism

I would like to implement a wrapper class similar to this:

```
class Wrapper[A](wrapped: A) {
  ...
}
```

And I would like it to behave like this:

```
val a: Wrapper[Int] = new Wrapper(2)
val b: Wrapper[Int] = new Wrapper(3)

val c = a + b  // "c" should be equal to Wrapper(5)
val d = a * b  // "d" should be equal to Wrapper(6)

val e: Wrapper[String] = new Wrapper("Hello ")
val f: Wrapper[String] = new Wrapper("World")

val g = e + f // "g" should be equal to Wrapper("Hello World")
```

But I do not want to manually implement the "+" and "*" methods inside the Wrapper class; because in general I do not know which methods the class A will have, and I want Wrapper to have all methods that A has, for any A.

**Is this possible at all (in Scala)?**

I suspect the answer is "no", but I would like to confirm. And if so, is there any alternative way to achieve this sort of generic behaviour?

Comment: Do you have an usecase for that?  Looks like `Wrapper[A]` should behave like `A`, so why not use `A`? What's the wrapper adding? Furthermore, if we have `x=new Wrapper(2); y=new Wrapper("foo")` what should be `x + y` ?

Comment: Yes, Wrapper[A] should behave exactly like A, but automatically wrap the result of any function applied to the wrapped object. So, even more generally, I would even be interested in the following:

   `val a = 3` ,  
   `val b = new Wrapper(2)` ,
   `val c = a + b  // "c" should be Wrapper(5)`.

The idea is that I want to be able to annotate/wrap an object of an arbitrary type A, and I want to be able to use this annotated/wrapped object as if it were an object of type A; but I want any object returned by a function that used the annotated/wrapped object to be annotated/wrapped as well.

Comment: The use case for this is that I want to be able to track whether some confidential objects have leaked.

Comment: As I said in the question, I think this is not possible. But I would appreciate to be proven wrong. Also, if anyone knows any programming language where this would be possible, I would be curious to know more about it.

Comment: For `x=new Wrapper(2); y=new Wrapper("foo"); x + y`, I would hope to have a compilation error.

Comment: Have you looked into Monads? Looks like what you want is an specialized IO Monad. Values can enter, but cannot leave the monadic context without specific calls that you could trace for your purposes. Within the monadic context, one can use all function/methods defined on the specific type A. e.g. your example above: `for {x <- SecureIO(2)} yield (x+3) // SecureIO(5)`.

Comment: Here's an answer where I discussed such approach: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40368833/764040 I think it could be a viable  alternative for what you're searching.

Comment: In a way, what I want is some form of very clever implicit conversion. If the compiler sees `Wrapper(5) + 3`, it should implicitly convert this to ` Wrapper(Wrapper(5).value + 3)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## It is possible, with some limitations.

It is actually possible to get the syntax you want. This solution will automatically 'implement' any method that exists in the wrapped class.

```
import scala.language.dynamics
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

object Temp {

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val test = new Wrapper("foo")
        println(test + "bar")
    }
}

class Wrapper[T](value: T) extends Dynamic {

    private val valueClass = value.getClass

    def applyDynamic(id: String)(parameters: Any*) = {
        val objectParameters = parameters map (x => x.asInstanceOf[Object])
        val parameterClasses = objectParameters map (_.getClass)
        val method = valueClass.getMethod(id, parameterClasses:_*)
        val res = method.invoke(value, objectParameters:_*)
        new Wrapper(res)
    }

    override def toString = value.toString
}
```

This works through [dynamic](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/Dynamic.html) classes. When a method is not found in a dynamic class it will call `applyDynamic` with the method name and parameters. It could also be made to work with fields. This is just a proof of concept and has several limitations that may or may not be able to be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible in **Scala**, and `Monoid` can help you implement this.

1. Create `Monoid` that help `lift` type with some method
2. implement the specify type `Monoid`  with `extend` from `Monoid` trait in `Monoid` Object
3. implement the `custom` method like the below `IntMonoid` `StringMonoid`.
4. Create the `MonoidOp` it's used for `implicit` convert `type` to the `MonoidOp`, like the below: `WrapperMonoIdOp` and `implicit def wrapperMonoid`.

Code Example:

```
//It's a Monoid that lift a type to Monoid
trait Monoid[A] {
  def mappend(a1: A, a2: A): A
}
object Monoid {
  implicit object IntMonoid extends Monoid[Int] { //Implement method with type
    override def mappend(a1: Int, a2: Int): Int = a1 + a2
  }
  implicit object StringMonoid extends Monoid[String] {
    override def mappend(a1: String, a2: String): String = a1 + "" + a2
  }
}
trait WrapperMonoIdOp[A] {  //MonoidOp it will be used to implicit convert type to the MonoIdOp
  val F: Monoid[A]
  val value: A
  def +(a2: Wrapper[A]): Wrapper[A] = {
    new Wrapper[A](F.mappend(value, a2.wrapped))
  }
}
class Wrapper[A](val wrapped: A) {
  override def toString: String = wrapped.toString
}
object TmpTest {
  implicit def wrapperMonoid[A: Monoid](a: Wrapper[A]): WrapperMonoIdOp[A] = new WrapperMonoIdOp[A] { //implicit convert the wrapper class to MonoidOp
    override val F: Monoid[A] = implicitly[Monoid[A]] //implictly Monoiid
    override val value: A = a.wrapped
  }
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val a = new Wrapper(1)
    val b = new Wrapper(2)
    println(a + b)
    val c = new Wrapper("hello")
    val d = new Wrapper("world")
    println(c + d)
  }
}
```

and If we invoke `+` with not implemented type, the compiler will throw compile error, like:

```
val a = new Wrapper(1.1)
val b = new Wrapper(1.2)
a + b // compiler will throw type mismatch.
```

Tutorial for this: http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/7.0/sum+function.html

Comment: Thanks, but that is not exactly what I am looking for. I would want "new Wrapper(1.1) + new Wrapper(1.2)" to automatically figure out that it should return "Wrapper(2.3)", even if I didn't implement the implicit converters from Float to Monoid. I also would like "(new Wrapper(6)) / (new Wrapper(3))" to return "Wrapper(2)", even though division is not the monoid's operation. And so on... (I know that I am wanting too much, and that is why I think it is impossible... But maybe using reflection (to discover the wrapped class's methods at run time) something could be done?)

Comment: @Ceilican, Different type has different `add` or `multiply` meaning, such as you create a custom type, you must need to implement `add` and `multiply` method by your self. `reflection` also can't do this. if you only need `Number`, you should check the [Numberic](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/math/Numeric.html) in **Scala**, this can help you for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it fully automatic, you'll have to implement '+' function for each type anyway. One of the possible approaches is to use implicit functions:

```
case class Wrapper[A](wrapped:A) {
  def +(b:Wrapper[A])(implicit sm: (A, A) => A) = Wrapper(sm(wrapped, b.wrapped))
}

object Test {
  def main(args:Array[String]) = {
    implicit val smInt:(Int, Int) => Int = {_+_}
    implicit val smString: (String, String) => String = {_+_}
    val a = Wrapper(2)
    val b = Wrapper(5)
    println(a+b==Wrapper(7))
    val c = Wrapper("Hello ")
    val d = Wrapper("World!")
    println(c+d==Wrapper("Hello World!"))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer to address the underlying question that got clarified in the comments: What we want is to have a 'secure context' where we can operate on any arbitrary type. Results of such operations should be captured in this secure context. Furthermore, we would like to apply operations on instances of the same type that are captured in such context and provide means to capture "free" values into that context.

I would argue that a Monadic context would address all these requirements. without the need to "implement the methods of the wrapped type".
Monads provide a context where computations can take place and such context is controlled by the monad implementation. Values in Monads are like the "Hotel California": *can always check in, but they can never leave.*

To illustrate the point, let's call this Monad "Context": `Context[T]`

Let's explore the examples provided in the question:

```
// Add two values in the context
val a: Context[Int] = Context(2)
val b: Context[Int] = Context(3)

val c = for {
           x <- a
           y <- b
        } yield x+y
// c:Context[Int] = Context(5)

//add a free value to a value in the context
val a: Context[Int] = Context(2)
val c = a.map(value => value + 3)
//c:Context[Int] = Context(5)

// We can transform types within the context and apply arbitrary functions
val transaction = for {
    user <- Context(user)
    amount <- Context(amount)
    account = user.account
    wallet = user.wallet
    funds <- account.withdraw(amount)
} yield wallet.deposit(funds)
```

The custom monad that needs to be developed will contain the  any computational strategy that is required to achieve our business or technical goals as well as methods to safely extract values from that custom context. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358462/chain-functions-in-different-way/40368833#40368833) for a concrete yet simple example.

Comment: This solution is also not exactly what I wanted, because you have to write `val c = a map {v => v + 3}` instead of simply `val c = a + 3`. But I guess this is the best we can currently.